# Representation of amplitude as height of wave

Tags: frequency, wavelength

This may seem an odd question and i fully realize the futility of a possible change in representation (having participated in a gazillion such discussions in mathematics). That said ...
I am thinking that using the height of a wave to represent amplitude is a very poor representation. It gives the impression that with an increase in amplitude above 1, the particle is traveling further in the same amount of time, that is, that the speed of light increases with an increase in amplitude and vice-versa. Perhaps thickness or color of the wave would have been a better representation. Then it would have been a clearer that wavelength and frequency are directly related to the distance the particle travels along the wave and the formula lamda=v/f easy to explain.
(As I understand it, changing the amplitude changes the energy given to the slinky and not the length (wavelength) or stretch (frequency).)

Comment: This appears to be an opinion based question, which makes it off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Strange as it may seem when the motion is simple harmonic the period and frequency of oscillation is independent of the amplitude.

So for a simple pendulum doubling the amplitude of small oscillations does not change the period (frequency) of the simple pendulum.

For mechanical waves doubling the amplitude does mean that the particles which are undergoing simple harmonic motion have to move a further distance in the same time and so have to travel faster.
The maximum speed of a particle undergoing simple harmonic motion at a frequency $f$ and amplitude $A$ is $2\pi f A$.
So doubling the amplitude doubles the maximum speed of a particle but does not change the speed of the wave.

For electromagnetic waves there are oscillations of electric fields and magnetic field and there is the speed of the wave.
If you choose a position you will find that at that position an electric field and a magnetic field at right angles to the electric field will change in magnitude and direction.
If the amplitude of the electric field is doubled so is the amplitude of the magnetic field and more power is transferred by the wave but the wave speed stays the same.
That doubling of the amplitude of a field does double the maximum rate of change of the field but that is not changing the speed at which the wave moves.

Comment: THANKS so absolutely much. I knew was not an official question, but I didn't know where else to ask. I really appreciate it! (Math teacher trying to be precise in physics is certainly a challenge.)

Comment: Again Farcher thank you  and if you don't have time for more I understand.
I am a slow thinker so it takes me a while to process ideas. For simple harmonic motion, I think this means that if you set up a left-right pendulum with a pen on it and a roll of paper being pulled through at 90o at a constant speed, then no matter the amplitude of the swing of the pendulum ("within reason") the same number of waves will be produced (frequency) with the same spacing (wavelength). So for longer swings (greater amplitude), the pendulum must move faster (since the pen must travel a longer distance).

Comment: You are correct.  Believe it or not the idea that the period was independent of amplitude for a mass oscillating at the end of a flexible bar was used in dynamics trolley experiment to do the timings when trying to find the acceleration.  The device was called Fletcher's trolley.  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BrrsVibtxg8. The trace obtained gave you a set of data for the distance traveled against time taken from which an acceleration could be obtained.

Comment: Again, my many thanks and for the link too. Restored my confidence too. (sorry to be so slow responding-internet jammed here with new years greetings).